# Read a JSON from cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp, json

I´m using a ajax requisition to take data from a Controller. The controller returns a json encode with the this data:

```
[{"Cliente":{"id":"1","nome":"Andre Figueredo","nome_representante":"Andre Figuerdo","email":"avs.fox@gmail.com","empresa":"Fox","area_atuacao":"Mocuton"},"Telefone":{"id":"1","cliente_id":"1","telefone":"11 33613529","telefone_representante":"11 97666-9899"},"Endereco":{"id":"1","cliente_id":"1","logradouro":"Av Washington","numero":"109","complemento":"","bairro":"santa luzia","municipio":"sao paulo","estado":"sp","cep":"02802-120"}}]
```

How can i read this json?

thanks!

Comment: I need to read on the jquery/javascript file.

Comment: -1 as you don't show any code, what you've tried or even clarify that you want to do this in javascript (what's with all the irrelevant tags?)

Comment: The purpose of telling you what's wrong with your question **is so you fix it**, and know how to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: **Do not** create another question. Fix this one.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to read in view you can use

as per http://php.net/json_decode, you need to specify you want an associative array instead of an object from json_decode:

```
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo "<pre>"
print_r($obj);
```

let me know if can help you further..

Comment: Thanks for your helper, but i need to read on the jquery/javascript file.

Comment: @Stark Please use this answer to get response in js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: let me know if i could help you more, And it would be glad if you will accept my answer, as it is useful to you so in future has someone with same issue which can utilize our answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method encode and return the result of `$content['Cliente']` instead of `$content`.

```
    $content = $this->Content->find('first', $options);
    return json_encode($content['Cliente']);
```

Now the result of `json_encode` will look like this which is appropriate for `json_decode`

```
  {"id":"1","nome":"Andre Figueredo","nome_representante":"Andre Figuerdo","email":"avs.fox@gmail.com","empresa":"Fox","area_atuacao":"Mocuton"},"Telefone":{"id":"1","cliente_id":"1","telefone":"11 33613529","telefone_representante":"11 97666-9899"},"Endereco":{"id":"1","cliente_id":"1","logradouro":"Av Washington","numero":"109","complemento":"","bairro":"santa luzia","municipio":"sao paulo","estado":"sp","cep":"02802-120"}
```